# How to display disqus on home page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, disqus

I have a problem with disqus plugin on wordpress. How to display disqus on home page. so the single page is to be a home page, maybe like that.
Any idea to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also unable to get disqus to work on homepage.
I can force the comments_template to appear by setting the following variable:
$withcomments = 1;

which makes the comments.php template appear but the discus plugin only kicks in if its on other pages other than home page.

Its as if the plugin itself prevents it if is_home() rather than listening to wp $withcomments variable

**UPDATE**

Can be fixed with plugin hack to disqus.php:

In `function dsq_comments_template` change the conditional `if(!(is_singular() && ( have_comments() || 'open' == $post->comment_status ))`

In mycase where I wanted it to work on home and an aggregate page for a custom taxonomy 'issue' I did the following:

after `global $comments;`
made a var for the more complex condition (it can go in the if instead)

`$pass = (is_home() || is_taxonomy('issue')) || (is_singular() && ( have_comments() || 'open' == $post->comment_status ));`

`if(!$pass) {`
`return`
`}`

... the rest of function ...

Be great if the developer made an option for this condition instead

Comment: Thanks! The path for `disqus.php` is `wp/wp-content/plugins/disqus-comment-system/disqus.php`

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean. Any comment plugin generally replace your current comment template and place their comment system. So make sure your `comments_template();` in right place.

Please send details of your problem.

Comment: OK I'm sorry, my trouble is how to display disqus on home page. so the single page is to be a home page, maybe like that. when I add comments_template(); on my script, it can show the comments what I need but not the disqus comment, just the standard comment.

Comment: hmm.. saw the page. Really wired! Can you send the code you used for the page? May be i can find the issue? You can use http://pastebin.com/ for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Disqus tutorial](http://project79.net/articles/using-disqus-for-comments-with-wolf-cms) with step-by-step instructions for a CMS. Does that help you with your installation?

I'm not sure what you mean by "not the disqus comment, just the standard comment", though. Can you explain?

Comment: I've already done install the disqus. But I wanna show on the homepage so I want like single.php as a homepage. But when I add comments_template(); on my script, that's appear standard comments template from wp. you can see it http://prntscr.com/1q3zo. the top is disqus comment, and the bottom is standard comment (that's what i mean).

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked great, but the

```
if(!$pass) { return }
```

was breaking the page, I replaced

```
    if ( !( is_singular() && ( have_comments() || 'open' == $post->comment_status ) ) ) {
    return;
}
```

with

```
    if ($pass = (is_home() || is_taxonomy('issue')) || (is_singular() && ( have_comments() || 'open' == $post->comment_status ))) {
}
```

leaving out the if(!pass){return}

not sure why